# How to Intent into specific Tab Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

T have two Activities: MainActivity and LoginActivity. I have one Fragment too, the name is TabFragment (with a TabLayout), its parent is MainActivity. How can I intent into the specific TabFragment from my Login Activity.

This is my Main Activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.confrag, new FragmentUtama()).commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.confrag, new TabFragment()).commit();
        }
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("login.conf", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        String username = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
        String password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");
        Log.d(TAG, "Username:"+username+"\npassword:"+password);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
```

And This my Tab Fragment:

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager, null);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new Adapterbaru(getChildFragmentManager()));
         tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();


        return view;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
    public class Adapterbaru extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        public Adapterbaru(FragmentManager fm){
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : {
                    return new Fragmentone();
                }
                case 1 : {
                    return new FragmentTwo();

                }
                case 2 : {
                    return new Fragmenttree();

                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
           return jumlah_tab;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch(position){
                case 0 : {
                    return "First";

                }
                case 1 : {
                    return "Second";

                }
                case 2 : {
                    return "Third";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. From your **`LoginActivity`**, pass tabs fragment `(FragmentOne, FragmentTwo, FragmentThree)` id as `0, 1, 2` through `Intent`.

   ```
   Intent intent  = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("FRAGMENT_ID", 0);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. In your **`MainActivity`**, get the fragment id from `Intent`

   ```
   // Inside OnCreate()
   int fragmentId = getIntent().getIntExtra("FRAGMENT_ID", 0);
   ```
3. From **`MainActivity`**, show `TabFragment` using `FragmentManager` and pass `fragmentId` to `TabFragment` using `Bundle`

   ```
   // Inside OnCreate()
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("TARGET_FRAGMENT_ID", fragmentId);
   TabFragment tabFragment = new TabFragment();
   tabFragment.setArguments(bundle);

   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.confrag, tabFragment).commit();
   ```
4. In **`TabFragment`**, get target fragment `(FragmentOne, FragmentTwo, FragmentThree)` id from `Bundle` and finally show desired fragment using `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(POSITION)` method.

   ```
   // Inside OnCreateView()
   int position = getArguments().getInt("TARGET_FRAGMENT_ID"); 
   viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);
   ```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you sir, same with my TabFragment

Comment: what's the difference between my code and ur's @FerdousAhamed?

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti See my point 3 and 4, you will find difference. Without TabFragment's  viewpager.setCurrentItem() how is it possible to select desired Fragment? TabFragment is the container of child fragments so you should pass data via TabFragment and control child fragment selection/visibility using it. Hope you will understand.

Comment: @DennyKurniawan If my answer solves your problem and seems useful to you then please give a up vote. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @DennyKurniawan If my answer seems useful please give an up vote. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: already sir, but someone downvote your answer. @FerdousaAhamed

Comment: upvoted I need to change putString to putInt. its working grate

Answer (score 1):

You can check it as

```
if(isFromLogin){
  viewpager.setCurrentItem(specificFragmentPosition);
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: hai, thanks sir for your answer, but i dont get it sir, i must send data from bundle or something else?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass position via bundle(intent) of the tabFragment you want to open whenever intent is done via LoginActivity

Answer (score 1):

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(posotion);
```

Answer (score 1):

From your LoginActivity pass Intents like this

In LoginActivity.class

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Fragmentone", 0); //pass zero for Fragmentone.
startActivity(intent);

Intent intent  = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("FragmentTwo", 1); //pass zero for FragmentTwo.
    startActivity(intent);

Intent intent  = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("FragmentThree", 2); //pass zero for FragmentThree.
    startActivity(intent);
```

In MainActivity.class

```
int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("Fragmentone", 0);
```

From Your activity pass like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", value);
FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
fragmentOne.setArguments(bundle);
```

and inside oncreateView of Fragment please define this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int strtext = getArguments().getInt("key");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: hello sir, thanks for your answer, but  my viewpager is inside my TabFragment. How can i access my viewPager?

Comment: Thank you sir, you save my day!

Comment: happy coding buddy.