# How to launch specific tablayout fragment from an activity

Tags: java, android

This Log_in is fragment and I want to launch this from my this activity. How can I do that?

```
Log_In log_in =new Log_In();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.relative_layout,log_in);
transaction.commit();
finish();
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Intent into specific Tab Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178728/how-to-intent-into-specific-tab-fragment)

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Log_In log_in =new Log_In();
FragmentTransaction fTransaction=getFragmentManager();
mTransaction.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.layout.container,log_in)  
.commit();
```